# Ive pushed my django app to production, but when i open the media files it raises a django.views.static.serve error

Tags: django

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://limitless-cliffs-18209.herokuapp.com/media/image/IMG_2516.JPG
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve

"/code/media/image/IMG_2516.JPG" does not exist

```
# settings.py


 MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

#urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: can you provide some code for more information for example your media and static configurations in settings.py file

Comment: # settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
#urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: can you provide code how you  uploading your image or any media

Comment: you mean from the model?

Comment: yes your model as well as how you are handling your file upload in views.py

Comment: Image = models.ImageField(upload_to=“image”)

Comment: Theres no views as its a restful api

Comment: there is some mistake in your url or path because on given url there is error message like this ` "/code/media/image/IMG_2516.JPG" does not exist` which says that look for media file inside code folder